# python zsh:killed in process of large sized matrix calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, zsh

I'm in a situation where I have a large sized matrix `a`. The size of `a` is 2708*2708 and type is <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>. I want to calculate some updating equation using `a`.

And the calculation process is like this:

```
adj = (a.dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(a)) / LA.norm(a.dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(a))
for k in range(1, 10):
    adj = (a.dot(adj).dot(a.T) +a.T.dot(adj).dot(a)) / (LA.norm(a.dot(adj).dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(eadj).dot(a)))
```

But this gives me

> zsh: killed

I guess the size of matrix causing this but how can I prevent this?

Is there a way to finish this calculation without `killed` error?

Comment: It's not clear you need to keep the entire list anyway; you never need any value except the previously computed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to use about 1000x more memory than you appear to need. You don't need to keep the entire list `zk`, because you never use any value except `zk[k-1]`. Just keep a reference to the *last* value computed, and replace that with the next value at each iteration.

Don't put a conditional in the loop to handle the first iteration specially; just pull that out as a pre-loop computation.

```
b = (a.dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(a)) / LA.norm((a.dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(a)))

for _ in range(1, 1000):  # One fewer iteration
   
    b = ((a.dot(b).dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(b).dot(a))
         / LA.norm((a.dot(b).dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(b).dot(a))))

print(b)
```

You also appear to be doing more work than necessary; the same value is used as the numerator and the denominator's argument at each step, but you compute it twice.

```
tmp1 = a.dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(a)
b = tmp1 / LA.norm(tmp1)

for _ in range(1, 1000):
    tmp1 = a.dot(b).dot(a.T) + a.T.dot(b).dot(a)
    b = tmp1 / LA.norm(tmp1)

print(b)
```

Comment: I tried coding not to use an array, like yours, but still got same result `killed`

Answer (score 0):

For the code posted, I get an output on my system. I am using a zsh shell and python 3.6. I am assuming you are using `numpy` as there is no mention of the same in the question.

There might be an issue with something else, not your code. Generally, a process is `killed` if it runs out of memory. You can track the memory of your code using `top`, in another terminal. Or you can try using a smaller sized matrix first to debug.

Comment: I first tried for a 3*3 matrix to see if that code would work, and yes, it worked. But for 2708*2708, `killed` appered. So the problem should be the size of matrix and memory. And I checked the memory usage, 
`PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP
66291  Python       99.7 01:13.28 2/1   0    15    35G+   0B     33G+   6629`. and the type of `a` is <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>.

Comment: You can try calculating the same in batches, then. Split your problem into subproblems which use smaller matrices.